# How to find frequency of repeated sentence in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, nltk, word-frequency

I have dataframe where I need to find the top 20 repeated sentence using Python, Please let me know how to go about it

```
Column A
Hello How are you?
This ticket is not valid
How are things at you end?
Hello How are you?
How can I help you?
Please help me with tickets
This ticket is not valid
Hello How are you?
```

Expected Output

```
Column A                         Frequency of Repeated sentence
Hello How are you?               3
This ticket is not valid         2
How can I help you?              1
.
.
.
```

Code so far

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\aaa\\abc\\Analysis\\chat.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1") 
df['word_count'] = df['Column A'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split(" ")))
df[['Column A','word_count']].head()

for i, g in df.groupby('Column A'):
   print ('Frequency of repeating sentence : {}'.format(g['Column A'].duplicated(keep=False).sum()))
```

**I need the result in a dataframe which can be written to CSV with "Column A" and "Frequency" columns in the final result**

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way using [`.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['ColumnA'].value_counts()
```

To add it as a column, you can do:

```
df['Frequency'] = df['ColumnA'].map(df['ColumnA'].value_counts())
```

Comment: i need a new column which gives the number of occurance, and when i did df['Frequency'] = df['Column A'].value_counts(), its giving NaN

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['count']=df.groupby(['ColumnA'] ).count()
df.sort_values(by='count', ascending=False)
print(df.head(20))
```

Comment: its throwing value error "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1"

Comment: Maybe do you have some Nan in you table. If needed, please try     df.fillna('' ",  inplace=True) before

Comment: there is no NAs in the file, there are few numbers but no NAs

Comment: Sorry I forgot [] => df['count']=df.groupby(['ColumnA'] ).count()

Comment: Yes pandas refuse to put the sentence as Index. the best is to apply the solution provide by YOLO, it works fine. Sorry for mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('Sentence')['Sentence'].transform('count')
df = df.sort_values(by = 'count', ascending = False)
df.head(20)
```

This will add a column 'count' to the original dataframe, which will contain the frequency of the corresponding sentence. `transform()` returns a Series that is aligned with the original dataframe.

Comment: but it is not grouping

Comment: You can use df.drop_duplicates() to remove the deleted rows after grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
freq_series= df.groupby(['Column A']).size()
new_df=pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA':freq_series.index,'frequency':freq_series.values})
new_df.to_csv('<your csv name>.csv')
```