# Couting repeated sentences from corpus

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I have a number of CSV files containing emails in one of the columns.
Each row has one complete email. Some of these emails are auto-responses and occur multiple times.

What is the best way to read through all the emails and count those sentences that keep repeating?

With just `pandas`, each row would have to contain just one sentence, but the data has emails, each consisting of many sentences. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59943539/how-to-find-frequency-of-repeated-sentence-in-a-file)

The input text:

> This is a new first line.
> This line is being added to file.
> And another line here.
>
> This is more text being added to file.
> And another line here.
> This is a new first line

**Expected output:**

| Sentence | Count |
| --- | --- |
| This is a new first line | 2 |
| And another line here. | 2 |
| This line is being added to file. | 1 |
| This is more text being added to file. | 1 |

What I have so far:

```
# Getting number of sentences with spacy
sentence_tokens = [[token.text for token in sent] for sent in doc.sents]
print(len(sentence_tokens))

# Getting sentence in list
[sent.text for sent in doc.sents ]
```

Output:

```
5

['This is a new first line.\n',
 'This line is being appended to file\nAnd another line here.\n',
 'This is more text being appended to file.\n',
 'And another line here.\n',
 'This is a new first line\n']
```

Using a counter for sentences.

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter([sent.text for sent in doc.sents ])
print(counts)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'This is a new first line.\n': 1, 'This line is being appended to file\nAnd another line here.\n': 1, 'This is more text being appended to file.\n': 1, 'And another line here.\n': 1, 'This is a new first line\n': 1})
```

Comment: Did you already manage to cut the emails into sentences and obtain a list of all the sentences?

Comment: If so, just `from collections import Counter; counts = Counter(list_of_sentences); print(counts)`

Comment: But won't the `Counter()` just return the number of sentences in the list? I need the number of times each sentence has appeared.

Comment: What makes you think that? Did you try it? Note how I wrote `counts` plural, with an s, as a hint that there is more than one count.

Comment: @Stef Edited the post with code and your suggestions. It returns the sentences and a count, but it's not the overall number of times they appear.

Comment: Try replacing `counts = Counter([sent.text for sent in doc.sents ])` with `counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(sent.text.split('\n') for sent in doc.sents))
` (where `chain` is `from itertools import chain`)